# Analytic expression of $g^{\sharp}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, dual-spaces

The analytical expression of $g^{\flat}\colon TM \to T^*M$ is given by

$$g^{\flat} = g_{ij}x^idx^j$$ with $x^i$ the coefficients of a $X\in TM$ in basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}$. Also, given the invertibility of $G = (g_{ij})$, $g^{\flat}$ is isomorphism and thus $g^{\sharp}\colon T^*M \to TM$ can be defined. According to bibliography, the analytical expression of $g^{\sharp}\colon T^*M \to TM$ is

$$g^{\sharp} = g^{ij}\omega_j\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}$$

with $\omega_i$ the coefficients of a $\omega\in T^*M$ in basis $d\omega^i$. I am trying to obtain the analytic expression of $g^{\sharp}$ starting from the definition of $g^{\flat}$ but I could not come up with an analytical solution. Could you please provide some guide lines?

Comment: I think you have a typo: do you mean $\omega_i$ is the component of $\omega$ relative to the basis $dx^i$? If so you're going to have a hard time because the $[g^{ij}] $ is the inverse matrix to $[g_{ij}]$. Sure, there could be explicit formulas for this (eg the weird formulas in linear algebra using cofactors and minors and what not), but they're not nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion here is notational. Keep in mind $g^\flat: TM\to T^*M$ is defined by $X\mapsto g(X,\cdot)$. The "analytical expression" is obtained by noting that if $X=x^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $Y = y^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, then
$$g^\flat(X)(Y) = g(X,Y) = g\big(x^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},y^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\big) = g\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\big)x^iy^j = g_{ij}x^idx^j(Y),$$
from which we conclude $g^\flat (X) = g_{ij}x^idx^j$.

Since $g^\sharp$ is the inverse of $g^\flat$, we can obtain a formula for it as follows: write $\omega = \omega_j dx^j$ in local coordinates. We want to find the unique $X$ for which $g(X,\cdot) = \omega$. Since $g(X,Y) = \omega(Y)$ for all $Y$, we must have $g_{ij}x^idx^j(Y) = \omega_j dx^j(Y)$, meaning $g_{ij}x^i=\omega_j$. But this is just a matrix-inversion problem written in Einstein notation; if $g^{ij}$ denotes the inverse of the matrix $g_{ij}$, then $x^i = g^{ij}\omega_j$. Thus
$$g^{\sharp}(\omega) = X = x^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = g^{ij}\omega_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},$$
which is the formula we wanted.

Comment: Thank you. We know that $g(X, \cdot)=g^{\flat}$. Why do we want $g(X, \cdot) = \omega$ to reach our result? Also, in the last line why we have $g^{\flat}(\omega)=X$?

Comment: The last line was a typo; should have been a sharp. As for why we look at $g(X,\cdot) = \omega$, keep in mind flat is the map which sends $X$ to $g(X,\cdot)$. If I want to calculate its inverse evaluated at $\omega$, then I need to find its preimage, i.e., what $X$ gives $g(X,\cdot)=\omega$.

To be clear, the maps are defined like $g^\flat: X\mapsto g(X,\cdot)$ and $g^\sharp: g(X,\cdot)\mapsto X$

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't got it yet. $g(X, \cdot)$ shouldn't be $g^{\flat}$? That is, $g^{\flat} \equiv g(X, \cdot)$, which means, $g^{\flat}(Y) = g(X, Y)=\omega \in T^*M = \{\omega\colon TM\to \mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: You are not understanding the answer. $g^{\flat}$ is a map that is independant of any vector field or differential form: it is an isomorphism between the tangent bundle and the cotangent bundle. Therefore, it cannot be equal to "$g(X,\cdot)$".

Comment: Yes, what @DIdier_ said. $g^\flat$ is an isomorphism from $TM$ to $T^*M$. It is not itself a covector. To get a covector you have to *evaluate* it at some $X\in TM$. And then $g^\flat(X)$ is in $T^*M$, so *now* it eats vectors, and we can write something like $(g^\flat(X))(Y)$. By definition though $(g^\flat(X))(Y) = g(X,Y)$ for $Y\in TM$.

So going backwards for the sharp, we suppose $X\in TM$ is such that $g^\flat(X) = \omega$, meaning $g(X,Y)=\omega(Y)$ for all $Y\in TM$ as discussed above. Using this we can figure out what the coordinates of $X$ are.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification!