# Sharp map on differential

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I do understand the definitions of $g^{\flat}\colon TM \to T^*M$ and $g^{\sharp}\colon T^*M \to TM$ [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3958293/analytic-expression-of-g-sharp) but I can not make the connection to obtain
$$\mathrm{grad} \, f=(df)^\#$$

Is it possible to obtain analytically the definition of gradient using the definitions of $g^{\flat}$ and $g^{\sharp}$?

Comment: That's the *definition* of the gradient on a Riemannian manifold, isn't it? What exactly is it that you want to obtain?

Comment: @HansLundmark is it possible to obtain the definition of gradient using the definition of $g^{\flat}$ and $g^{\sharp}$?

Comment: $\mathrm df$ is a linear form approximating $f$. Linear forms can be represented as scalar multiplication by a vector. This vector by which we multiply when applying $\mathrm df$ is the gradient. That's the intuition in Euclidean space with the standard inner product. On a Riemannian manifold, the metric allows us to do similar things with differentials of real functions on the manifold. $(\mathrm df)^\#$ is the vector we obtain this way.

Comment: What you wrote in your original post is the definition of the gradient using $g^\sharp$. It is the case where $g$ is the one-form $df \in T^*M$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos in this direction, I understand that $df_p (v_p)= \langle \mathrm{grad} f_p, v_p \rangle_g$ with $v_p \in T_p \mathcal{M}$ 
and $g$ Riemann metric. In this way, I think that we can define $df_f$ as a bi-linear mapping  $df_p \colon T_p \mathcal{M} \times T_p\mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathrm{grad}f_p$ fixed. From this, I think we can define $df_p^{\flat}\colon T_p \to T_p^*\mathcal{M}$ but I could not go any further to compute $(df)^{\sharp}$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is the other way around. You don't define $df$ in terms of $\mathrm{grad} \, f$. It is $df$ that is the more fundamental object. It is $\mathrm{grad} \, f$ that is defined in terms of $df$. What you wrote, $df(v) = \left< \mathrm{grad} f, v\right>$, is the definition of $\mathrm{grad} f$ (not the definition of $df$....$df$ already makes sense without talking about the metric)

Comment: @Nick what confuses me is how we can use $\sharp$ mapping which is defined as far I can see for $g$ to define gradient. You wrote $df\in T^*M$, I understand, thus, we may apply $\sharp$ to $df$ to obtain $(df)^\sharp\in TM$? I do not see the connection on how we can used $\sharp$ defined for metric $g$ in order to define $\mathrm{grad}f$. Analytically. Also If that is possible we may conclude that $df_p (v_p)= \langle \mathrm{grad} f_p, v_p \rangle_g$. That is the opposite direction of my last comment?

Comment: Maybe your confusion is that you are using $g$ as the symbol for the metric tensor? Then the notations $g^\flat$ and $g^\sharp$ are misleading. It is the symbols $\flat$ and $\sharp$ which are the maps, so $\flat \colon TM \to T^*M$ and $\sharp \colon T^*M \to TM$. If $g$ is the metric, then $g^\sharp$ and $g^\flat$ are not really correct uses of the notation.

Comment: @Nick maybe I'm misunderstanding what you meant but I'm not sure why you say $g^{\flat}$ and $g^{\sharp}$ are incorrect uses of notation. They're the musical isomorphisms taken with respect to the metric $g$, so including the $g$ in the notation makes perfect sense. (also if we want to be super picky with notation then we would have to define $\text{grad}_g(f):= g^{\sharp}\circ df$ (the gradient with respect to the metric $g$ of $f$), because this is the composition of the covector field $df:M\to T^*M$ with $g^{\sharp}:T^*M\to TM$, which gives the vector field $\text{grad}_g(f):M\to TM$)

Comment: ...though usually it's not necessary to be so precise, so we often write $g^{\sharp}(df)$ or just $(df)^{\sharp}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo that's right, I just meant it's usually written $(df)^\sharp$, without including $g$ in the notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like maybe your confusion is that you have a preconceived notion of what the gradient is, and are wondering why this definition agrees with what you have previously thought of as the "gradient"?

Maybe you are thinking (from elementary calculus) of the gradient of $f$ as the vector with components $\nabla f = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \; \dots, \; \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \right)$. This in general does *not* agree with the $df^\sharp$ definition. It only agrees when you take the standard Euclidean metric on $\Bbb{R}^n$ (the ordinary "dot product"):
$$ g(v,w) = \left<v,w\right> = v_1w_1 + v_2w_2 + \cdots + v_nw_n $$

But of course you do not have to take this as your metric. A general metric looks like
$$ g(v,w) = \sum_{ij} g_{ij} v_iw_j $$
where $g_{ij}$ are some collection of smooth functions (obeying certain relations from the definition of a metric, like symmetry : $g_{ij} = g_{ji}$, etc.). Then the gradient (i.e. $df^\sharp$) is the vector field so that $df(v) = g(df^\sharp,v)$ for all vectors $v$. Let's use $c_i$ for the components of $\mathrm{grad} f = df^\sharp =(c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n)$. By plugging in $v=e_i=(0,0,\dots,1,\dots,0)$, you see that
$$ \begin{align*}
df(e_i) &= g(df^\sharp,e_i) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} &= \sum_j g_{ji} c_j 
\end {align*}$$
So you see, in general $c_i \neq \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$. By solving these equations for $c_i$, you get
$$c_i = \sum_j g^{ji} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$$
where $g^{ij}$ are the components of the inverse of the matrix $g_{ij}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please let me ask a few things in order to consolidate. According to your last comment $\sharp \colon T^*M \to TM$. This means that $(df)^{\sharp}  \colon T^*M \to TM$?

Comment: No, $(df)^\sharp$ is not a map. It is just a vector field. $\sharp$ is the map/function, and $(df)^\sharp$ means applying the map to $df$.

Comment: I am not sure that I have understand it. I think you use $\mathrm{graf}f=(df)^{\sharp}$ but what I am trying to understand is how this equation is obtained from $df$ by raising an index.  Am I wrong?

Comment: This equation is *not* "obtained". This equation is a definition of what the symbol "$\mathrm{grad} \, f$" means. You cannot "derive" or "obtain" it, because it is simply the "rule" or "definition". It is still not clear what you are asking.

Comment: If you want to talk more (instead of making more and more comments), go to the chat room I made: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117743/gradient-discussion